# Document Class for Briefing Notes

Tags: document-classes, documentclass-writing

I was wondering whether there was a document class for briefing notes/memos in LaTeX. If there is not any what is the easiest way of making my own?

**PS:** Sorry, I should have given an example. Here are a few (PDF): http://writingforresults.net/Acro_3/templates.pdf more specifically but I need something like the one on page A-25 of the link. Only the first page is the problem, it should have the following attributes:

1. First line: "Memorandum to XXXX", where XXXX depends on the content.
2. Title: centered with the last line underlined.
3. Below title produce "For XXXX", where XXXX depends on the content.
4. Then comes "Summary", it can not exceed the first page, it should be in a box, with "Summary" centered inside the box on the first line.

Comment: What do you mean with briefing notes/memos? Can you show an example (pdf or screenshot)?

Comment: Sorry folks I added a link to a few examples.

Answer (score 3):

`texMemo` is a dedicated class for writing memos. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{texMemo}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\memoto{Donald E. Knuth}
\memofrom{TeX Stack Exchange}
\memosubject{Your honorary membership to TeX.SX}
\memodate{\today}
\logo{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{texsx}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\noindent
We all are glad to welcome you as a honorary member of our site. 
\end{document}
```

[image: memo]

Download, documentation and examples are here:

- [texMemo: A Simple Memo Class for LaTeX and LyX](http://blog.oak-tree.us/index.php/2010/08/02/texmemo)

Since memos are very similar to letters, you could use a letter class and customize it as desired. Have a look at the corresponding TeX catalogue section for a list of classes and packages:

- [Writing Letters, Faxes, Memos, and Newsletters](http://texcatalogue.ctan.org/bytopic.html#letters)

Answer (score 1):

You may find it useful to refer to this link: http://WritingForResults.net/classic.pdf. This file introduces the concept of a briefing note and explains its significance. It then provides detailed guidance on the content, organization, format and style of briefing notes. Finally, it provides guidance on how to approach the task of writing a briefing note.

Hope that's helpful.

Regards,

Rob Parkinson

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.